# Selenium Test image on Ubuntu

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a docker selenium image on ubuntu and have my selenium test cases executed with it. But I do see quite a few random failures.

Does anyone know the good version of:

```
1) Chrome, 
2) Chromedriver, 
3) Selenium, 
4) TestNG, 
5) Docker(?)
6) JDK
```

that totally it may give me the highest success rate ? Thanks.

Comment: What type of random failures?

Comment: This is the type of failure I got: "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no all-purpose correct version combinations here. I believe that you can evaluate this trying continuously different versions and see which one of them behaves the best for you.

There will always be some random failures caused by setup issues.

1) Chrome

This depends on the application you are testing and how it behaves on the given browser version. Some changes to the browsers affect in a terrible way some web apps. So we can't propose you specific version without any knowledge about your app. It really depends on many factors.

2) Chrome Driver 
Each version of Chrome Driver is recommended for specified chrome versions so it depends on the browser version.

3) Selenium has some bug fixes in it's newer versions so in the perfect case you should use the newest version. But there is no guarantee that it will fit you the best.

4) TestNG - it depends on the way you use it so nothing more can be said here.

5) Docker - not sure if the Docker version can affect in some way the test executions. But it might depend on the selenium version.

6) JDK depends on your tests implementation. Are you using new java features and etc. Actually it should have minimal impact over the test executions